# unit test undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.groups.map')

Tags: javascript, angular, unit-testing, typescript, karma-jasmine

I have that script

```
  groups: Group[] = []

  constructor(

  ) {
    this.groups = AuthenticationService.getUserGroups()
    let menuList: any = []
    this.groups.map((permission: Group) => {
      menuList.push(...this.menuGenerator[permission.nomeGrupo.split('-')[1]])
    })
  }
```

And when I run `npm run test`, just appear that error `TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.groups.map')`. I want to know what is the best way do fix that. I put `spyOn` to `getUserGroups`, but isn't work. How can I put some value for the variable? Thanks a lot! I really need to learn that!

Answer (score 1):

Putting a spy replaces your function.

This means that it doesn't return anything anymore.

This means that you start with

```
groups = [];
```

Then you spy on your function

```
spyOn(AuthenticationService, 'getUserGroups');
```

And then you get

```
groups = undefined;
```

To resolve that, simply return a value in your spy :

```
spyOn(AuthenticationService, 'getUserGroups').and.returnValue([]);
```

**EDIT** Because you're in the constructor, you can't spy on the component itself, since it isn't created.

Gladly for you, you have the prototypal inheritance. Instead of spying on the service instance, you can spy on the prototype :

```
spyOn(AuthenticationService.prototype, 'getUserGroups').and.returnValue([]);
```

You should put this right under your `describe('MyComponent')`, so that's the first thing called.

Comment: Great! But where I put that? I put before fixture.detectChanges()! But doesn't work...

Comment: Wait, I didn't see you were in the constructor. Let me edit my question.

Comment: Great! I will try now, but if spyOn can spy in contructor, what is the best way to put the script? ngOnInit?

Comment: I get some error in 'getUserGroups' when I put .prototype! =)

Comment: `ngOnInit` would be great yeah ! What kind of error are you getting ?

Comment: Ok! [ts] Argument of type '"getUserGroups"' is not assignable to parameter of type '"getUserData" | "getPersonData" | "getAuthentication" | "getPermissionsList" | "getRolesData" | "...'. I will put in onInit

Comment: That means you don't have the `getUserGroups` method in your class. Be sure to make no typo. [Here is a stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-testing-template-pz5cyf?file=app/hello.component.spec.ts).

Comment: Thanks man! Its works if I put script in ngOnInit()! But then appear another errors! =) at least that works!

Comment: I like how people always ignore the answers they're given, and later tell you they resolved their issue thank to you ... Any way, I'm glad you resolved it and that I could somehow help. Consider marking your answer as resolved, or deleting it if you feel it will only help yourself and not other users !